# Number of permutations of $n$ pairs of letters such that no two adjacent letters are identical

Tags: combinatorics

> Find the number of permutations of $n$ pairs of letters $a_1 ,a_1;a_2,a_2;a_3,a_3; ....;a_n,a_n$ (each  pair consisting of identical letters), such that no two adjacent letters are identical.

My attempt:

Total number of permutations without any restrictions is $\frac{(2n)!}{(2!)^n}$, now we have to subtract the number of permutations in which at least a pair of identical letters are adjacent, but I am not able to find out how many such permutations exist.

Can you find out the number of such permutations if not is there any other way around to solve the problem.

There is another way too,

We can arrange $a_1$'s and $a_2$'s in $4!$ ways. Now in the $5$ gaps formed we can arrange $a_3$'s, $a_4$'s and a single $a_5$ in $\frac{5!}{2^2}$ ways.

After the second round of arrangements,  10 gaps are formed. In these gaps we can arrange the other $a_5$, $a_6$'s , $a_7$'s, $a_8$'s, $a_9$'s and a single $a_{10}$ in $8(\frac{9!}{2^4})$ ways.

The total number of permutations is something like this

$(4!)(\frac{5!}{2^2})(8)(\frac{9!}{2^4}).............$

We would have to find a pattern in the product. At the end it would be dependent on what reminder $n$ gives when divided by $5$ I guess.

Comment: are you familiar with inclusion-exclusion?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the following family of sets $A_i=\{\text{ways to permute having } a_i \text{ together}\}$. To count those, just notice that you can create a (super?) letter, say $b_i=a_ia_i$ and just notice, by the same argument you used, $$|A_i|=\frac{(2(n-1)+1)!}{2^{n-1}}.$$
Can you find $|A_i\cap A_j|$ for $i\neq j$? If so, just use inclusion exclusion getting
$$\text{All ways }-\left |\bigcup _{i=1}^nA_i\right |=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}-\sum _{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\sum _{X\subseteq \binom{[n]}{i}}\left |\bigcap _{x\in X}A_x\right |,$$
where $\binom{[n]}{i}=\{X\subseteq [n]=\{1,2,\cdots ,n\}:|X|=i\}$.

> In general $\left |\bigcap _{x\in X}A_x\right |=\frac{(2(n-|X|)+|X|)!} {2^{n-|X|}}$, so the final number of ways is $$\sum _{i=0}^n\binom{n}{i}\frac{(2n-i)!}{2^{n-i}}(-1)^i.$$

Comment: Is the notation |A_j and A_i| an accepted form of proof? This is just an intersection A and B, why is sentential logic being mixed with algebraic proof? Referenced from Velleman(cp3), its meaningless to do this notation because it doesn't prove anything, it's just a statement. A_x and B_y, such that x not in y.

Comment: Please elaborate I'm trying to reason with the conclusion

Comment: Okay so maybe I should elaborate. The size of the intersection would consist of A OR B first to bind the set. Then you can operate A and B on that set. Otherwise youre just making a set of 2 values that youre calculating between while showing no union between the foundational permutations what so ever. Thus making a statement not a proof, does this clarify what I mean

Comment: @Barb I am not proving anything. I am calculating. The proofs of the methods of inclusion-exclusion I used can be found in any book dealing with sieves or incidence algebras over posets.

Comment: Oh I see, forgive me I thought we needed to provide proof on our calculations on this forum

Comment: @Phicar, i am not familiar with the  mathematical notations you used.

Comment: @Vishnu.v.r Can you tell me what you don't understand so I can make it accessible to you?

Comment: @Barb Yeah, imagine if we had to proof everything we say. I invite you to ask a separate question if you have some difficulties understanding this topic, I will be down to help.

Comment: @Phicar okay thanks for the help